# Vlookup property not working in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am searching a variable selrow which holds string values in a sheet. Sometimes it shows error

> unable to get vlookup property of worksheet function class

I have also put the error handling code but still error occurs.

**Code**

[this where error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ikDl.png)

```
for i=1 to last_row
    'code
    selrow= range("D"&i)
    opening_inventory_today = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    opening_inventory_today = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(selrow, ActiveSheet.Range("A4:B" & lr), 2, False)
```

Comment: Put the `On Error` before the for loop.

Comment: Needs a bit more code for context.

Comment: @UGP  what happens is i take a value from a row then activate other sheet and look up sel row. i have presumed the opening_inventory_today = 0. then the value changes if i get the value from lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `On Error Resume Next` is not handling the error, you need to trap the cases that `VLookup` was unable to find `selrow`, and then raise an error message (or whatever you want).

Try the code below:

```
If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(selrow, ActiveSheet.Range("A4:B" & lr), 2, False)) Then
    opening_inventory_today = Application.VLookup(selrow, ActiveSheet.Range("A4:B" & lr), 2, False)
    ' rest of your code here

Else
    MsgBox "VLookup was unable to find " & selrow, vbInformation
End If
```

Comment: Let me explain... If you remove `On Error Resume Next` then Vlookup will give you error and you will not even reach the line `If Not IsError(opening_inventory_today) Then` :)

Comment: ++ Now it makes sense :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks for the heads up, I do realize there might be multiple other issues, like working with `ActiveSheet`, etc.

Comment: Now since you have rectified your answer, I deleted mine :D